# Not all variables appear in Locals and Autos window in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I write some custom apps for AutoCAD in VS2010 in VB.NET. Two days ago something went wrong with "Locals" and "Autos" debug windows. When i step from line to line while debugging using F11 key, no variables that are being created during program run appear in these windows. I've tested the same project in VS2008 and everything was just fine there. I guess I've tweaked something in VS2010 settings, but i don't know how to get things back. I've already reinstalled VS2010 with no luck...

Under the link there are two images that may help you to understand what exactly i mean by posting this.

http://picasaweb.google.com/acyxou/Public?authkey=Gv1sRgCJqb3-KBwPHBMw&feat=directlink#5527425721063250738

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you disable the debug compiler option? Did you enable the optimize compiler option?

Comment: thanks for response leppie, but i can hardly imagine what are you talking about) Are these in project's properties or in VS Options? Can't find these settings....

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem.  The fix is as leppie suggested, disable the optimization option.  For me using C++ the location for this option is:

Right click your project solution -> Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Optimization -> set Optimization to disabled